# Spring boot security with keycloak not working for graphql

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, graphql, keycloak

Apologies for the lengthy post. I have a spring boot application which contains both rest and graphql APIs. Also I'm using keycloak auth server. I want to add keycloak authentication for both apis. Setup is as follows

**Dependencies**

I have added following dependencies as mentioned in [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_boot_adapter).

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>13.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    //-- other dependencies
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>13.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Additionally I'm using following dependencies for spring security and expediagroup graphql kotlin support.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.expediagroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-kotlin-spring-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Security Configuration**

```
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakConfiguration
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakSecurityComponents
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.client.KeycloakClientRequestFactory
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.client.KeycloakRestTemplate
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy

@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = [KeycloakSecurityComponents::class])
class KeycloakSecurityConfig: KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Autowired
    var keycloakClientRequestFactory: KeycloakClientRequestFactory? = null

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        super.configure(http)
        http.csrf().disable().cors().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll()
    }

    @Autowired
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        val keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider()
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(SimpleAuthorityMapper())
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider)
    }

    @Bean
    override fun sessionAuthenticationStrategy(): SessionAuthenticationStrategy? {
        return RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(SessionRegistryImpl())
    }

    @Bean
    fun KeycloakConfigResolver(): KeycloakConfigResolver? {
        return KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver()
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    fun keycloakRestTemplate(): KeycloakRestTemplate? {
        return KeycloakRestTemplate(keycloakClientRequestFactory)
    }
}
```

**Endpoints**

These are my sample rest and graphql endpoints.

**GraphQL**

```
import com.expediagroup.graphql.spring.operations.Query
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture


@Component
class HelloQuery: Query {

    fun helloWorld():CompletableFuture<String>{
        return Mono.just("hello from graphql").toFuture()
    }

}
```

**Rest Controller**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody

@Controller
class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    @ResponseBody
    fun hello(): String {
        return "hello from rest"
    }

}
```

**Results**

When I run the application and test the APIs get following results.

**Rest API** - work successfully
[image]

**GraphQL** - 404 error

[image]

But when I remove all security configs graphql api also work successfully.
[image]

My problem is can I use graphql with keycloak spring security. If yes what am I doing wrong here?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Based on discussions in the graphql-kotlin GitHub project, I expect it should work with Spring Security. Try and narrow down the issue by simplifying your code as much as possible. I would suggest start with the basic `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency, without keycloak and without any customizations (just the default HTTP basic auth). See if you are still getting a 404 from the `/graphql` endpoint.

Comment: I also noticed that you have a WebFlux application, but you are using `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which is meant for servlet based applications. Because of this, I expect any security configuration is not taking effect.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana it's working with basic spring security. Issue arises when keycloak security is integrated

Comment: Hi @Ruchira , I also facing issue making Spring+GraphQL+Keycloak: did you manage to make it work? I always get 401 even if it logs it loaded urls from auth-server-url

Comment: I've been running into similar issues while trying to write integration tests with Keycloak/Spring Security/GraphQl. I know it's been a while, but are there any updates on the situation?

Comment: @Beast I had to do some changes in security config file. I have added it as an answer. Since it's been a long time I'm not sure about it's validity. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Needed to do some changes to security config file.

- adding corsFilter
- adding securityWebFilterChain

Also I'm using dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.expediagroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-kotlin-spring-server</artifactId>
        <version>${graphql-kotlin-spring-server.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

It worked for me. Posting the answer hopefully will help someone.

**Security config file**

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@Configuration
internal class SecurityConfig(
        private val monitoringProperties: MonitoringProperties,
        private val securityProperties: SecurityProperties,
        private val graphQLConfigurationProperties: GraphQLConfigurationProperties
) {
    companion object {
        const val AUTHORITY_ACTUATOR = "AUTHORITY_ACTUATOR"
        const val AUTHORITY_ACCESS_MONITORING = "AUTHORITY_ACCESS_MONITORING"
        const val AUTHORITY_ACCESS_INTERNAL_API = "AUTHORITY_ACCESS_INTERNAL_API"
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = ["spring.security.user.passwordGenerated"], matchIfMissing = true, havingValue = "false")
    fun userDetailsService(): MapReactiveUserDetailsService {
        val actuatorUser = User
                .withUsername(securityProperties.user.name)
                .password("{noop}${securityProperties.user.password}")
                .authorities(AUTHORITY_ACTUATOR, AUTHORITY_ACCESS_MONITORING, AUTHORITY_ACCESS_INTERNAL_API).build()

        val monitoringUser = User
                .withUsername(monitoringProperties.username)
                .password("{noop}${monitoringProperties.password}")
                .authorities(AUTHORITY_ACCESS_MONITORING)
                .build()

        return MapReactiveUserDetailsService(actuatorUser, monitoringUser)
    }

    @Bean
    fun corsWebFilter(): CorsWebFilter {
        return CorsWebFilter(UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource().apply {
            registerCorsConfiguration(
                    "/${graphQLConfigurationProperties.endpoint}",
                    CorsConfiguration().apply {
                        allowCredentials = true
                        allowedOrigins = listOf("*")
                        allowedHeaders = listOf("*")
                        allowedMethods = listOf("*")
                    }
            )
            registerCorsConfiguration(
                    "/${graphQLConfigurationProperties.subscriptions.endpoint}",
                    CorsConfiguration().apply {
                        allowCredentials = true
                        allowedOrigins = listOf("*")
                        allowedHeaders = listOf("*")
                        allowedMethods = listOf("*")
                    }
            )
            registerCorsConfiguration(
                    "/web/*",
                    CorsConfiguration().apply {
                        allowCredentials = true
                        allowedOrigins = listOf("*")
                        allowedHeaders = listOf("*")
                        allowedMethods = listOf("*")
                    }
            )
        })
    }

    @Bean
    fun securityWebFilterChain(
            http: ServerHttpSecurity
    ): SecurityWebFilterChain {



        return http {
            httpBasic { }
            configureKeycloakAuth()
            csrf { disable() }

            authorizeExchange {
                

                // actuator and monitoring
                authorize(EndpointRequest.to("health", "info"), permitAll)
                authorize(EndpointRequest.to(PrometheusScrapeEndpoint::class.java), hasAnyAuthority(AUTHORITY_ACCESS_MONITORING))
                authorize(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint(), hasAuthority(AUTHORITY_ACTUATOR))

                authorizeGraphQL()

                // rest
                authorize(anyExchange, denyAll)
            }
            requestCache { disable() }
        }
    }

    private fun ServerHttpSecurityDsl.configureKeycloakAuth() {
        oauth2ResourceServer {
            bearerTokenConverter = ServerBearerTokenAuthenticationConverter().apply { setAllowUriQueryParameter(true) }

            jwt { jwtAuthenticationConverter = KeycloakJwtAuthenticationConverter() }
        }
    }

    private fun AuthorizeExchangeDsl.authorizeGraphQL() {
        authorize(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/${graphQLConfigurationProperties.endpoint}"), permitAll)

        authorize(antPattern = "/${graphQLConfigurationProperties.endpoint}", access = hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER"))
        authorize(antPattern = "/${graphQLConfigurationProperties.subscriptions.endpoint}", access = hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN"))
        authorize(antPattern = "/web/*", access = permitAll)

        if (graphQLConfigurationProperties.playground.enabled) {
            authorize(antPattern = "/${graphQLConfigurationProperties.playground.endpoint}", access = permitAll)
        }
        if (graphQLConfigurationProperties.sdl.enabled) {
            authorize(antPattern = "/${graphQLConfigurationProperties.sdl.endpoint}", access = permitAll)
        }
    }
}


class KeycloakJwtAuthenticationConverter : Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> {

    private val delegate = JwtAuthenticationConverter()

    override fun convert(jwt: Jwt): Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken> {
        return Mono.just(jwt)
                .map { source: Jwt -> delegate.convert(source) }
                .map { auth ->
                    when (auth) {
                        is JwtAuthenticationToken -> try {
                            KeycloakToken.fromOauth2Token(auth)
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            auth
                        }
                        else -> auth
                    }
                }
    }

}

class KeycloakToken(authorities: Collection<out GrantedAuthority>, private val principal: AuthenticatedUser, private val credentials: Any) :
        AbstractAuthenticationToken(authorities) {

    companion object {
        fun fromOauth2Token(oauth2Token: JwtAuthenticationToken): KeycloakToken {

            val id = UUID.fromString(oauth2Token.name)
            val jwt = oauth2Token.principal as Jwt
            val email = jwt.claims["email"] as? String
            val firstName = jwt.claims["given_name"] as? String
            val lastName = jwt.claims["family_name"] as? String
            val fullName = jwt.claims["name"] as? String

            if (email == null || firstName == null || lastName == null || fullName == null) {
                throw RuntimeException("User Details incomplete - name not set of user with id $id: email: $email, first name: $firstName, last name: $lastName, full name: $fullName")
            }

            val realmAccess = jwt.claims["realm_access"] as Map<*, *>
            val roles = (realmAccess["roles"] as List<*>).map { it.toString() }

            val authorities = oauth2Token.authorities.toMutableList()
            authorities.addAll(roles.map { SimpleGrantedAuthority(it) })


            return KeycloakToken(
                    authorities = authorities,
                    principal = AuthenticatedUser(
                            id = id,
                            email = email,
                            firstName = firstName,
                            lastName = lastName,
                            fullName = fullName,
                            roles = roles.toList()
                    ),
                    credentials = oauth2Token.credentials
            )
                    .apply {
                        details = oauth2Token
                        isAuthenticated = true
                    }
        }
    }

    override fun getPrincipal() = principal

    override fun getCredentials() = credentials
}
```